# How to check if the item has dependencies in the database before updating its status?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am a new developer of ASP.NET and Linq-To-Entities. I am trying right now to write a general method which will take care of  checking if there is any dependency on the item before updating its status. For example, there are many employees under each division. What I want to do that when the user wants to update the status of the division from an Active to Inactive, then this method will tell him that there are active users underneath it. of all users belong to that division will be inactive. This thing is applicable to the other scenarios such us Department, Division and Unit.

I have the following Database structure:

```
Departments Table: ID, Name, Code, Status, UserId
Divisions Table: ID, Name, Code, Status, UserId, DeptID
Units Table: ID, Name, Code, Status, UserId, DivID
Users Table: ID, Name, Status
Status Table: ID, Status
```

**Could you please tell me how to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to rethink your model if you're expecting multiple users per Dept/Div/Unit, because your current model only has one user for each, which I assume is not what you want. Also it doesn't seem like you want the opposite either (A user belonging to a single Div/Unit/Dept, which would be done by adding DeptId etc to the Users table.)

Instead it looks like you want a many-to-many relationship between Departments and Users, and the correct way to model this is to give those relationships a dedicated table, such as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE DepartmentUserRel
   (
       DepartmentId int,
       UserId int,

       PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentId, UserId)

       CONSTRAINT FK_DepartmentUserRel_Department FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentId)
       REFERENCES Department (Id)

       CONSTRAINT FK_DeparmentUserRel_User FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
       REFERENCES Users (Id)
   )
```

Similar tables should exist for each many-to-many relationship between two of your other tables, but they're not necessary for many-to-one/one-to-many relationships.

Once you have the right model, you should really reconsider storing *computed values* such as Status in the Departments table at all - you should in fact compute them each time you query, and updating the Status should mean updating all users, not just the Status field in the Department.

You should instead use views to create a virtual view of the database structure as you placed it in your question. If we assume the above DepartmentUserRel table has another `Status bit,` field in it, where TRUE would indicate an active user and FALSE inactive, such that you want to declare a virtual `Status` field in the Department table which is true if any of the users for that department are active, you create the view something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW DepartmentView AS
SELECT D.Id as Id, D.Name as Name, Code, SUM(DU.Status) as Status
FROM Departments D, DepartmentUserRel DU
WHERE DU.DepartmentId = D.Id
```

You query from the DepartmentView much the same way you would query from a regular table, eg `SELECT * FROM DepartmentView`

Here's the caveat: Views can not be directly inserted or updated, because they may take fields from several tables, but INSERT/UPDATE should only modify one table at a time. We do in fact only want to update one table at a time here - the DepartmentUserRel table. If we want to set `Status` in DepartmentView to FALSE (inactive), that instead means we want to set `Status` in the DepartmentUserRel table to FALSE for all relationships of users to that department. We can do this by creating a trigger which catches attempted updates to the view.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trigger_Update_Department on DepartmentView
INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Status FROM inserted) = FALSE) 
        UPDATE DepartmentUserRel SET DU.Status = FALSE
        FROM DepartmentUserRel DU, Departments D
        WHERE DU.DepartmentId = D.Id
END
```

(*Note that all those code examples are conceptual. I've not tested them and only partially remember the syntax for them, but you should be able to fix them by knowing what to search for.*)